# Create Locale Directories and String Files

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm starting to learn programming for Android and I have problem with [THIS LESSON](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs)There was similar questions, but related to an earlier version of Android Studio.
**I can't create new folder (for country values), like this:
[CLICK FOR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQMvL.png)** or this:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

P.S. Sory for my bad english :D

Comment: Can you explain in more detail about 'why' you "can't create new folders" ?

Comment: Is this about programming or about how to create a folder in general?

Comment: I'm starting to learn the Android Studio. This is not a a bug, but just do not know how can I create a new folder (values-es). Can you help me? D

Comment: Actually I just had the same problem you did, 1 min, I'll write it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the folder using the `explorer` like `Finder` on mac os...or something else in windows or linux. After that copy the file of strings to that folder and Android Studio automatically will detect it.

If you want to use the Android Studio, just right click in your `strings.xml` file and open the translations editor 
[image].

In the translation editor click on `add locale`
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but "strings.xml (fr)" can be located in a folder values?
I do not need to create a folder "values-fr" for it?

Comment: Yup, and name the file `strings.xml`

Comment: So how to create a folder values-fr? I know, i'm begginer :D

Comment: Just follow the steps in my answer.

Comment: Ok, now i know (i think so :D) Thanks

Comment: I checked, it works Thanks

Answer (score 3):

to create the directories (similar, but possibly slightly different named than the example you linked) in Android Studio by [right click] on 'res' and select 'new' -> 'android resource directory'.

This will open pop up window asking you some info.

find 'locale' in the list on the left. then select it. Then press the ">>" button.

This will ask you the language (and if you choose 'region' where that language is spoken, so 'en-rUS' is English-US, where as 'en' is just English (no region))

Click the 'ok' button.

Then you will need to 'sycn' your project with your gradle files.

To do this, click 'Tools' -> 'Android' -> 'Sync Project with gradle files'

I just tested this with Android Studio 1.5.1 right now. Should work for you. (the 'translate Strings.xml' as was recommended by Sandro Machado is also valid, but I would personally prefer to make the folders first, but that is just me)

---

[image: How android Studio shows different tranlsations]

So Android Studio 'hides' the folders from you. if you look at your file system, then you will see you DID create the folders. However you will first need to copy strings.xml into each folder before Android Studio will show you a screen like what I have. (honestly I think this is stupid... and hadn't realized this behavior before) But I hope that explains the situation to you. (the above method will make the right directories if you want, but you'd have to copy the strings.xml from your /values folder to each folder after that.

The 'Translations Editor' might be alright for small projects, but I feel the raw text files would be better for large projects. (just a 'feeling', nothing to back that up, and possibly just my own work-flow more than anything.)

Comment: I haven't "android resource folder" option  ( 'res' and select 'new' -> 'android resource folder'.)
http://images.tinypic.pl/i/00740/wmx78jngg2ql.png

Comment: Sorry, "folder" and "directory" are basically interchangeable. (technically they aren't on windows, but for most people they are the same) I'll update the answer.